# How can call a function in service on click event in angular2?

Tags: html, angular, angular2-services

This is the working plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/FOJHofLSgLRB4Po5Li6B?p=preview .
On clicking the classes the corresponding content at the bottom changes, but this is hardcoded & so is it possible to have something that makes the content to come from a service like this :

```
export class Subjectservice {
  getClass(id : number) : any {
    if(id==15)
      return [{label:  'Science', state: false},{label:  'Computer Science', state: false},{label:  'Social science', state: false},{label:  'Environmental Studies', state: false}];
    else if (id==68) 
      return [{label: 'English', state: false},{label:  'Hindi', state: false},{label:  'Mathematics', state: false},{label:  'Science', state: false}];
    else if (id==910) 
      return [{label: 'English', state: false},{label:  'Hindi', state: false}{label:  'Social science', state: false},{label:  'Sanskrit', state: false}];
    else
    return [{label: 'English', state: false}{label:  'Pol Science', state: false},{label:  'Comp Science', state: false},{label:  'Social science', state: false}];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a small angular 2 app created which is calling a service on click. Please see the source code [here](https://github.com/khanstudio-github/Angular2AppASPNet) of Github. You can see the **heroService.ts** in *app/services* folder and **heroes.component.ts**.

> **Repository**: https://github.com/khanstudio-github/Angular2AppASPNet/tree/master/Angular2StarterApp/Angular2StarterApp

I hope this would help you. Please feel free to ask if facing some issue.

Comment: In my .html I have a <md-card id=15 (click)="getClass(id)" > & on its click I want to call a function in component.ts which further calls a function in service.ts. While calling the function from html, I have to pass the id of the card as well, on the basis of which a particular array would be returned from the service, & so I need to pass the id, somehow I cant manage to execute this...

Comment: Is this a working plunker of the same code you are taking about ? or this is some different version of it ? The one which you have mentioned above.

Comment: It is the same, somehow the angular material cards I am using dont seem to work on the plunker, so the classes written in bold, you can assume them to be the cards

Comment: Rather than calling click like this in **(click)="view='one'"** use a function instead, like (click)="checkView('one')" .

Than is your AppComponent class call your service with this parameter i.e one. See the **dashboard.component.ts** file in `app/components/heros` folder. You need to call service like this on checkView function as I have called service component in **ngOnInit()**

Comment: Thanks, I went through your code in dashboard.component.ts, I am absolutely new to angular2 & have no idea what is this doing : .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5))

Comment: Not to worry this is just picking first 5 records from result set return by service. In your case this would something like `.then(serviceData => this.resultHtml = serviceData )`

`.then()` is just a promise callback means it will only run when your service returned some results. if service fails somehow, this will be ignored.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118547/discussion-between-himanshi-gupta-and-amkhan).

Answer (score 0):

Create a service class:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class SubjectService{

getClass(id:any):number
{
//write your logic here....
}
}
```

Inject service in your AppComponent:

```
    import{SubjectService} from './subject.service';
            @Component({
            selector: 'my-app',
            template:'<div>.....</div>',
            providers:[SubjectService]
            })

    export class AppComponent
    {
        constructor(private subjectSer:SubjectService)
        {
            // now subjectSer can be used as instance of your service i.e. subjectSer.getClass(1);
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you. Feel free to ask any question.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont know while calling subjectSer.getClass(id); it is giving an error that it doesn't recognise 'id' : [ts] Cannot find name 'id'. any